# Exclude specific page from Jekyll / Hugo generated page

Tags: jekyll, liquid, hugo

On my project, under "pages" folder, there's the projects.md and it generates the preview of all the pages under the "projects", and currently I have 4 items there, alphabetically from A to D, projectA.md etc.

I don't want all 4 thumbnails on the projects page, so I made "secondary.md" page and I would like if only projectC.md and projectD.md would generate on that one.

Can I use "exclude" on the front matter for this?

Comment: Can you provide a link to the repo or a code snipped? From what you wrote it is not quite clear what exactly you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

No, exclude will not help you.

You should make a frontmatter variable `show_on_home: true` for the ones you want on the home. Then you should adjust your home template and use the logic below.

For Hugo you can then use 'range', like this:

```
{{ range where .Site.RegularPages "Section" "projects") }}
  {{ if .Params.show_on_home }}
    ...
  {{ end }}
{{ end }}
```

For Jekyll you need a slightly different syntax:

```
{% for item in .site.projects %}
  {% if item.show_on_home %}
    ...
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```